# XPath is different when read from csv file

Tags: python, csv, xpath, utf-8, scrapy

So, I am reading an XPath from a csv file (**with encoding - UTF-8**)

The XPath in question is:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2[.// *[contains(text(), 'Job Description')]] and following-sibling::h2[.// *[contains(text(), 'External')]]]
```

However, when read from the file and into the program it is getting modified to:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2[.//Â *[contains(text(),Â 'JobÂ Description')]]Â andÂ following-sibling::h2[.//Â *[contains(text(),Â 'External')]]]
```

which is causing Xpath: Invalid Predicate error.

Any reason as to why this is happening and how can I rectify it? I am reading the csv file using csv library from python.

```
import csv    
with open("input.csv", mode = 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter = ';')
        next(reader) #Skip reading the header
        InputData = [] #Store the data rows as a list of lists
        for row in reader:
            InputData.append(row)
```

csv file is

```
url;link_regex;title_css;job_desc_xpath
https://careers.leidos.com/jobs/6726525-junior-agile-developer-active-top-secret-clearance-required ;^(.*/jobs/) ;h1::text ;//*[preceding-sibling::h2[.//*[contains(text(),'Description')]] and following-sibling::h2[.//*[contains(text(),'External')]]]
```

Comment: Show *how* you are reading it. Make a [mcve]

Comment: Never mind, using encoding as utf-8 in open file, solved the issue. Should I delete the question or leave it alone?

Comment: post your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
with open("input.csv", mode = 'r') as file:
```

with

```
with open("input.csv", mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as file
```